# Assign value to variable based on condition (value of other variable) in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I want to assign value to a variable based on if another variable is null or not.
I know there is error in the same code i am giving below,
but i tried like this and don't know how i can get it done.
although it gives clear picture of what i want to do.

```
declare 
lv_var1 varchar2(500);
lv_var2 varchar2(20);
ld_date date;

begin 
lv_var2 := 'sample value';
lv_var1 := case ld_date when not null 
                        then lv_var2
           end case;

dbms_output.put_line(lv_var1);         
end;
```

i want to assign the the value of `lv_var2` into `lv_var1` when `ld_date` is not null, else `lv_var1` will be null.

The error i am getting is `ORA-06550`.
This is probably because of the case statement, but what else can i use in place of it to get the result.

Please help. 
Thanks ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the **CASE** expression, no need of `CASE` keyword with the **END** keyword while using it in **SQL**. `END` keyword is required in **PL/SQL**.

Using **CASE** as **SQL**:

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    lv_var1 VARCHAR2(500);
  3    lv_var2 VARCHAR2(20);
  4    ld_date DATE;
  5  BEGIN
  6    ld_date:= SYSDATE;
  7    lv_var2 := 'sample value';
  8    lv_var1 :=
  9    CASE
 10    WHEN ld_date IS NOT NULL THEN
 11      lv_var2
 12    END;
 13    dbms_output.put_line(lv_var1);
 14  END;
 15  /
sample value

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Using **CASE** in **PL/SQL:**

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    lv_var1 VARCHAR2(500);
  3    lv_var2 VARCHAR2(20);
  4    ld_date DATE;
  5  BEGIN
  6    ld_date := SYSDATE;
  7    lv_var2 := 'sample value';
  8    CASE
  9    WHEN ld_date IS NOT NULL THEN
 10      lv_var1    := lv_var2;
 11    END CASE;
 12    dbms_output.put_line(lv_var1);
 13  END;
 14  /
sample value

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The same could be written using **IF** in **PL/SQL:**

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    lv_var1 VARCHAR2(500);
  3    lv_var2 VARCHAR2(20);
  4    ld_date DATE;
  5  BEGIN
  6    ld_date    := SYSDATE;
  7    lv_var2    := 'sample value';
  8    IF ld_date IS NOT NULL THEN
  9      lv_var1  := lv_var2;
 10    END IF;
 11    dbms_output.put_line(lv_var1);
 12  END;
 13  /
sample value

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lv_var1 := case when ld_date is not null 
                        then lv_var2
           else null end case_;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lv_var1 := case when ld_date is not null 
                    then lv_var2
            end;
```

or

```
select nvl2(ld_date,lv_var2,null) into lv_var1 from dual;
```

Comment: No, it is still wrong. `ELSE` has nothing to do with OP's error. `ELSE` is optional, and not mandatory. The issue is syntax in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
declare 
lv_var1 varchar2(500);
lv_var2 varchar2(20);
ld_date date;
begin 
ld_date := null;  -- initialize the variable with null, or another value like sysdate
lv_var2 := 'sample value';
lv_var1 := case when ld_date is not null  -- case statement adapted
                        then lv_var2
           end;

dbms_output.put_line(lv_var1);         
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey you can try nvl2 function which can also suffice your requirement.
>   Hope this helps.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  lv_var1 VARCHAR2(500);
  lv_var2 VARCHAR2(20);
  ld_date DATE:= NULL;
BEGIN
  lv_var2 := 'sample value';
  SELECT nvl2(ld_date,lv_var2,NULL) INTO lv_var1 FROM dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_var1);
END;
```